# Can you disable a Nintendo Switch "phone-home" feature that tracks played games?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

It is a well know fact that thanks to the stupid implementation of the trophy feature a modern PS console will forever remember any game you ever played.
Played a demo? The trophies will be there.
A friend lent you a game and then you returned it? The trophies will be there.
You bought a game and then you refunded it for some reason? *The trophies will still be there.*

Considering that the Nintendo Switch never had any trophy system to begin with, there shouldn't be any similar issue right? Wrong.
I recently realized that Nintendo would often send you surveys to your Nintendo account about games you just played. Even if the game is offline and you never "registered it" to get the "coin bonus" added to your account.

This means that the Nintendo Switch track what games you played and sends the data to Nintendo when you get online.
This also means that if your friend lend you a game to try it, you don't like it and remove it... you can still receive a mail from Nintendo later telling you that "The new [insert game here] **2** is available on the store!"

.... Obviously you could just disable promotional mails in you account setting but...
I was wondering: is there any actual way to disable the data sharing in the first place?

Comment: I don't think you can, once you play a game it's permanently added to your history, and whenever you go online those data are shared with everybody. Just for the sake of curiosity, what's stupid with trophies? You don't like them in general or how they are managed?

Comment: @pinckerman will gladly further elaborate in chat if you wish but mostly just the issue I mention in the question: no way to remove them, even if it was just a demo, a game you sold and don't care about etc. Since they forcehanded trophies in a competition model like "more trophies = better player" they also removed the ownership of the trophy from the player to be able to make stats and comparison to add on your profile.
I should be able to remove a game if I no longer own or care about it. Even worse, if I didn't like it and refunded I should not be shown it every time I look at my trophies

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda frustrating that you can't remove a game once you unlock a trophy, i.e. games started by someone else on the wrong profile... But I'm glad that they are not tied to the game's owner, I like to borrow games from friends and keep the trophies.

Comment: You could probably create a new local account to play games on. However, if you decide you like the game and want to keep it, you won't be able to transfer the saves to your main account.

Comment: @Nolonar If you are talking about the PS trophy thing... I already do that when I have games I don't want to keep trophies for (demo games and so on)